# Regular Expression which returns true if string contains any of a>b or a<b or a>=b or a<=b or a!=b or a==b

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help with Regular Expression which returns true if string must contains "alphanumeric followed by any Comparison Operators(like >,<,==,!=,>=,<=) followed by Comparison Operator)

if string contains any of the below case return true else return false
a>b a=b a<=b a!=b a==b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex will do that

```
 [\w]+[ ]*(!=|<|>|<=|>=|==)[ ]*[\w]+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind can you help me with the regexp that must contain exact 2 semicolon (;;).

Comment: It is simple. `[;]{2}` will do

Comment: @Thanga You should do operators like `[=<>!]=|[<>]` so that an assignment operator like `=` is not allowed

Comment: `"a=!=!=<><><><><><!!!=b"` - true

Comment: @Thanga regarding [;]{2}, it accepts only if string is ;;   but it is not what i expected.  It will return as
a;b;c = true
a;b    = false
a;b;c;d = false

Comment: @RedLaser - Thank you for suggestion

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - It is fixed now and my answer is updated. Thanks for the alert

Comment: @LokeshReddy - `[;]{1}[\w]*[;]{1}` will do your need

Comment: `/[\w]+[ ]*[=<>!]{0,1}[=]{0,1}[ ]*[\w]+/.test("ab")` - true, `/[\w]+[ ]*[=<>!]{0,1}[=]{0,1}[ ]*[\w]+/.test("a=b")` - true. Just list all operators explicitly in `(|)` :)

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Thanks again .. Answer updated

Comment: @Thanga regarding [;]{1}[\w]*[;]{1} , it is working even if we has 3 semicolons (;;;), but my need is to return true only if 2 semicolons are there. See the conditions
;;  - true     a;b;c - true   a;b;c;b - false    a;b - false  ; - flase.     More than 2 semicolons return false, less than 2 semi colons return false